# Calculus 2: Integrate Fraction Subtracted from whole number

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm stuck on the following problem:

[image]

What is the right approach to this problem?  I'm new to calculus so a more detailed explanation would be awesome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Integration is linear, so $$ \int \left( 3 - \frac 2 {x-5} \right) \, dx = \int 3\,dx - \int \frac 2 {x-5}\, dx. $$

Comment: ahhh!  thank you